# Какие отличия между @NotEmpty, @NotBlank и @NotNull?

Tags: java, jpa, bean-validation

В разных примерах Entity класса, по разному валидируют поля

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=3)
@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Email
@Size(min=6, max=80)
@NotBlank(message="{register.email.invalid}")
@Column(name = "email", unique=true)
private String email;

@Column(name = "first_name")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide your first name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide your last name")
private String lastName;

@Transient
private String password;
```

Но какие между ними различия и что следует использовать и в каких случаях ?

А также если указана аннотация `@Size(min=6, max=80)` нужно ли дополнительно проверять с помощью `@NotBlank` или других аннотаций ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@NotBlank` применяется только к строкам и проверяет, что строка не пуста.
`@NotNull` применяется к `CharSequence`, `Collection`, `Map` или `Array` и проверяет, что объект не равен `null`. Но при этом он может быть пуст.
`@NotEmpty` применяется к `CharSequence`, `Collection`, `Map` или `Array` и проверяет, что он не `null` имеет размер больше 0.

Аннотация `@Size(min=6)` пропустит строку состоящую из 6 пробелов и/или символов переноса строки, а `@NotBlank` не пропустит.

Comment: тогда разумнее использовать `@NotBlank` для тех полей которые обязательны для заполнения в форме регистрации.
А `NotNull` даже пропустит string test = ""; тогда получается что поле может быть и не заполнено в фронтенде, верно ?

Comment: Да, всё правильно.